# Find rows where any two columns are not unique in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select

Sort of the reverse of finding duplicate rows. I have a table with a bunch of columns, and I want to find where data isn't the same in two columns. So...

If I have this:

```
------------
col1 | col2
------------
  A  |  1
------------
  A  |  1
------------
  A  |  2
------------
  B  |  1
------------
  B  |  1
------------
  B  |  3
------------
  B  |  1
------------
```

I want to find this:

```
------------
col1 | col2
------------
  A  |  1
------------
  A  |  2
------------
  B  |  1
------------
  B  |  3
------------
```

But if I have this:

```
------------
col1 | col2
------------
  A  |  1
------------
  A  |  1
------------
  B  |  1
------------
  B  |  1
------------
  B  |  1
------------
```

I want to find this:

```
Empty set
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--why would your second example be an empty set?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a bit on your requirements.

Comment: It's strange that the second example comes back empty, while the first example contains `{A,1}` and `{B,1}` tuples. Please explain.

Comment: The table contains records of individual files belonging to a project (col1), that are owned by a user (col2). I need to flag projects that have files owned by more than one user. All I really need to know is which projects have this condition. If none of them do, return nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can assume you have a unique id column also, you can do something like

```
select *
from the_table t
where not exists (
    select 0
    from the_table t2
    where t.col1 = t2.col1
    and t.col2 = t2.col2
    and t.id < t2.id
)
```

Comment: Note, this won't return the empty set for the second example. This will return (A,1) and (B,2). I *think* that is what you actually meant. Let me know if not

Comment: It's close. I don't really understand the subquery stuff in MySQL yet. But yeah, it needs to return nothing when all col2 are identical for each group of col1's. Thanks for the help! I'm going to try tweaking your example a bit... maybe I can figure it ou.

Answer (score 0):

this works if the user wants to select a value of greater than 1. but if the user want to have an empty if Col2 has the same value greater than 1, this query won't work.

```
SELECT * FROM
         (SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2 FROM tableName) as iQuery
WHERE iQuery.Col2 > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
Select col1, col2
From tablename
Group by col1, col2
Having count(*) >  1;
```

This solution will return duplicated records, as requested in the last comment from the question owner.

Comment: that won't work - you won't select the unique values in the first example

Comment: This will not return `{A,1}` and `{B,1}` for the first example.

Comment: But he will not have rows where the data exists in more than one row. I think the example are inconsistent against the description.